# Wildcard sql date query

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server

i am working on a project and stuck on a `sql` `query`, query does not give any error nor returning any result tell me where the problem is

```
SELECT
      barcode
    , Date
    , timein
    , timeout
    , totaltime
    , leave
    , remarks
FROM TimeSheet
WHERE barcode = @barcode
     AND Date LIKE '@year-07-%'
```

i am passing 2 values in variable at runtime `@barcode` `@year`
but if i run the query with values type explicitly  in sql editor it works fine and return values

if run this

```
SELECT
      barcode
    , Date
    , timein
    , timeout
    , totaltime
    , leave
    , remarks
FROM TimeSheet
WHERE barcode = 123456
     AND Date LIKE '2013-07-%'
```

it return values

Comment: wht is ur codebehind is it vb or c#

Comment: What is the datatype of your `Date` column?

Comment: the datetype of `Date` column is `date`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

SQL Server does not expand the variable in `'@year-07-%'`.

Assuming the `@year` parameter is a `varchar` and the `[date]` column is a `date`, you could try this instead:

```
where  convert(varchar(10), [date], 120) like @year + '-07-%'
```

Or even better:

```
where  datepart(year, [date]) = cast(@year as int)
       and datepart(month, [date]) = 7
```

Comment: still not displaying any result

Comment: @MohsinMustufa - what's the declared data type of `@year`?

Comment: What's the data type of the `[date]` column?

Comment: data type of the [date] column is `Date`

Comment: If the data type is `date`, these queries should work?  Can you reproduce the problem on http://sqlfiddle.com ?

Comment: `@year` is of string type

Comment: Your sqlfiddle contains an empty table, so of course that's never returning any rows. :)  Could you add some example data?

Comment: I am sorry, but this will not perform well on a large table

Comment: @t-clausen.dk: I'd be surprised if there was a big difference.  The cost of date to string conversion is trivial compared to disk I/O.

Comment: @Andomar I tested it today. It took 7 seconds on my table where the other query took less than 1 second. I also tried it in other situations. It does not work well

Comment: @t-clausen.dk: Did your test setup have a key on the `Date` column?

Comment: Thanks buddy its done now 
actually the gridview is in update panel and it visibility is false thats why its not showing any record

Answer (score 3):

The following will be efficient if there is an index on DATE column

```
SELECT
      barcode
    , Date
    , timein
    , timeout
    , totaltime
    , leave
    , remarks
FROM TimeSheet
WHERE barcode = @barcode
     AND Date >=dateadd(month,6,dateadd(year,@year-1900,0))
     AND Date <dateadd(month,7,dateadd(year,@year-1900,0))
```

Comment: same result not returning any value

Comment: @MohsinMustufa then test your data. This will work and perform best

Answer (score 1):

This one is what Andomar suggested.

```
create table #timesheet (barcode int, entrydate date, other_col varchar(20))

insert into #timesheet (barcode, entrydate , other_col)
values (123456,'2013-07-01','helloA')
    ,(123456,'2013-07-02','helloB')
    ,(123457,'2013-07-02','helloC')
    ,(123456,'2013-06-01','helloD')

DECLARE @YEAR VARCHAR(4) = '2013'
    ,@barcode int = 123456

Select *
From #timesheet
Where barcode = @barcode
And convert(varchar(10), entrydate, 120) like @year + '-07-%'

Select *
From #timesheet
Where barcode = @barcode
And datepart(year,entrydate) = cast(@year as int)
And datepart(month,entrydate) = 7
```

Comment: quite helpful in creating schema in sqlfiddle